# Why does Django template block/include include external <table> tag?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Consider the below code:

```
<table id='table1'>
  {% if model_name == 'TransactionsTable' %}        
    {% block transactions_create %}            
      {% include "snippets/transactions_create_and_update.html" with form=form %}            
    {% endblock transactions_create %}                 
  {% endif %}
</table>
```

I have another `<table>`, 'table2', within `transactions_create_and_update.html`.

```
<table  id=table2>abc</table>
```

Table2 was appearing outside of it's parent element. See image below - table2 should be inside of table1

[image]

So after some testing I tried closing table1 early (first line):

```
<table id='table1'></table>
  {% if model_name == 'TransactionsTable' %}        
    {% block transactions_create %}            
      {% include "snippets/transactions_create_and_update.html" with form=form %}            
    {% endblock transactions_create %}                 
  {% endif %}
```

Then it looks like this

[image]

I don't really understand what is going on in either scenario.

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include) - think this is part of the answer but I don't know what to do with it:

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render
> this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate
> and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means
> that there is no shared state between included templates – each
> include is a completely independent rendering process.
>
> Blocks are evaluated before they are included. This means that a
> template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that
> have already been evaluated and rendered - not blocks that can be
> overridden by, for example, an extending template.

Comment: It is about HTML issue, the children of table tag should be th or tr, etc, not including any plain text directly

Answer (score 0):

I had too many 'includes'. It turned out that one-level deeper I had a  element that wasn't closed properly.